# Material ui button does not take into consideration the css styles to override the default one

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I'm using a private bootstrap css styles into my react app. I want to update the styles of the default material ui components with the bootstrap styles.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import 'cg-bootstrap/core/build/cg-bootstrap-standard.css'

const Sample = () => {
const [value, setValue]= useState('');

const handleChange = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    }
return (
<Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">

<Grid item>
<Typography>Label text</Typogrpahy>
</Grid>
<Grid item>
<TextField value={state.value} variant="contained" onChange={handleChange}/>
</Grid>
<Grid item>
<Button 
variant="contained"
type="submit"
classes={{
contained: "btn btn-md btn-primary",
}}>
Submit
</Button>
</Grid>
</Grid>
)
}
```

cg-bootstrap-standard.css

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black; }
  .btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: black; }
  .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125rem rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125rem rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.5); }
  .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary:disabled {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: black; }
  .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
  .show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: black; }
    .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
    .show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125rem rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.5);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125rem rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.5); }
```

While I look on chrome console, I got :
[image: transpiled compoenent]

[image: styles]

[image: styles1]

the `btn btn-primary` styles were overwritten and I want to apply their styles as the final styles applied to the button not the default styles of material-ui. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StylesProvider` with prop `injectFirst`

> The StylesProvider component has an injectFirst prop to inject the
> style tags first in the head (less priority)

```
import { Button, StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core";

function Sample() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      {/* Your component tree */}
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        classes={{ contained: "btn btn-md btn-primary" }}
      >
        Hello
      </Button>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

By default MUI injects its style sheets as the last element(s) of the `<head>` tag so that is why it takes higher priority than your Bootstrap stylesheet. The above solution should remedy the situation.

https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order